# Google AI Platform training - wait for the job to finish

Tags: machine-learning, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vertex-ai, google-ai-platform, gcp-ai-platform-training

I've built an AI Platform pipeline with a lot of parallel processes. Each process launches a training job on the AI Platform, like this:

```
gcloud ai-platform jobs submit training ...
```

Then it has to wait for the job to finish to pass to the next step. For doing this, I've tried to add the parameter `--stream-logs` to the above command. In this way, it streams all the logs until the job is done.

The problem is, with so many parallel processes, I run out of requests for getting logs:

```
Quota exceeded for quota metric 'Read requests' and limit 'Read requests per minute' 
of service 'logging.googleapis.com'
```

But I do not need to actually stream the logs, I just need a way to tell the process to "wait" until the training job is done. Is there a smarter and simpler way of doing this?

Answer (score 2):

I've just found that I can use the Python API to launch and monitor the job:

```
training_inputs = {
    'scaleTier': 'CUSTOM',
    'masterType': 'n1-standard-8',
    ...
}

job_spec = {'jobId': 'your_job_name', 'trainingInput': training_inputs}


project_name = 'your-project'
project_id = 'projects/{}'.format(project_name)


cloudml = discovery.build('ml', 'v1')

request = cloudml.projects().jobs().create(
    body=job_spec,
    parent=project_id
)
response = request.execute()
```

Now I can set up a loop that checks the job state every 60 seconds

```
state = 'RUNNING'
while state == 'RUNNING':

    time.sleep(60)
    status_req = cloudml.projects().jobs().get(name=f'{project_id}/jobs/{job_name}')

    state = status_req.execute()['state']

    print(state)
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the error message you are experiencing, indeed you are hitting a [quota exceeded](https://cloud.google.com/logging/quotas) for Cloud Logging, what you can do is to request a quota increase.

On the other hand, about an smarter way to check the status of a job without streaming logs, what you can do is to check the status once in a while by running `gcloud ai-platform jobs describe <job_name>` or create a Python script to check the status, this is explained in the following [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/training/docs/monitor-training#python).

Answer (score 0):

In case you need to use the Python Vertex SDK to monitor job status, I suggest doing the following:

Name your jobs with a unique display name. I use the timestamp in UNIX format as a suffix for the name

```
from datetime import datetime 
display_name = f"my-fancy-training-job-{datetime.now().strftime('%s')}"
```

Create and launch your job. We simulate a Custom Job but the same procedure can be applied to any Vertex AI job processes (like Batch Prediction jobs and more)

```
from google.cloud import aiplatform
from google.oauth2 import service_account

client = aiplatform.gapic.JobServiceClient(
    credentials=service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
        'my-service-account.json'
    ),
    client_options={"api_endpoint": f"{MYREGION}-aiplatform.googleapis.com"}
)
custom_job = {
    "display_name": display_name,
    "job_spec": {
        "worker_pool_specs": [
            {
                "machine_spec": {
                    "machine_type": "n1-standard-4",
                },
                "replica_count": 1,
                "container_spec": {
                    "image_uri": MYDOCKERIMAGEURI,
                    "command": [],
                    "args": MYDOCKERARGS,
                },
            }
        ]
    },
}
parent = f"projects/{MYPROJECT}/locations/{MYREGION}"
response = client.create_custom_job(parent=parent, custom_job=custom_job)
```

When the job is submitted, we can monitor its status by filtering it by the known display name (which is univocal).

```
import time
stop = False
while not stop:
    time.sleep(60 * 2)
    request = aiplatform.gapic.ListCustomJobsRequest(
        parent=parent,
        filter=f"display_name={display_name}",
        page_size=1
    )
    result = next(client.list_custom_jobs(request=request).pages)
    if len(result.custom_jobs) > 0:
        state = result.custom_jobs[0].state.name
        if state == 'JOB_STATE_SUCCEEDED':
            stop = True
            print(f"{display_name} FINISHED WITH STATUS: '{state}'")
        elif state in ['JOB_STATE_PENDING', 'JOB_STATE_QUEUED', 'JOB_STATE_RUNNING']:
            stop = False
            print(f"{display_name} IS IN STATUS: '{state}'")
        else:
            stop = True
            print(f"{display_name} FINISHED WITH STATUS: '{state}'")
    else:
        stop = True
        print(f"{display_name} NOT FOUND")
```